# kendo treeview template does not bind to a source of array of 3 objects

Tags: json, templates, kendo-ui, treeview

I have my data source as an array of 3 objects serialized into a Json string. However, when I bind it to my kendo treeview template, it just has 3 same level root items but does not display the children in the tree view. I m using HTML5/Javascript source. My JSON has object properties like Descripion: image: and Children: which again has many child objects in it.  I cannot proceed further without this. Please help me as it is needed very soon.
 The actual JSON string......JsonData: Array[3]. The first object has been broken accordingly.
0: Object
Children: Array[35]
Description: "Dimension"
HasChild: false
ImgSource: "/Content/images/dimension.png."

i need my template displaying the "Description" & "image" property as root and the "Children" containing the same.
My template script is as below:

```
var template = kendo.template($("#pateltree-template").html());
var modeldata1 = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource(
   {
       data: jsondata,  
   }
 );

var options = {
    //dataSource: [modeldata1, modeldata2, modeldata3],
    dataSource: modeldata1,
    template: template,

    dataTextField: ["Description"],
    dragAndDrop: true,
    schema: {
        model: {
            items: "Children"
        }
    }

};
$("#PatelTree").kendoTreeView(options);
```

TEMPLATE
     #:item.Description# 
        # if (!item.Children) { #
         #:item.Description# 
        # } #

Please tell me what is wrong.

Comment: Could you post jsondata contents?
You template looks weird, you don't need if statement there. It does same if u dont have it.

Comment: @Japi: Yeah......I agree with you. I defined my template incorrectly. Thanks for the help and excuse for the delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I defined an incorrect template. The correct template is as follows:

```js
< script id = "pateltree-template"
type = "text/kendo-ui template" >
  < span data - type = "#:item.Type#"
data - element - type = "#:item.DataElementType#"
data - isroot = "#:item.Expanded#"
data - fieldkey = "#:item.FieldKey#" >
  < img src = "#:item.ImgSource#" / >
  < span class = "desc" > #: item.Description# < /span>
    </span >
  < /script>
```

> The template uses the below mentioned properties of the model:
>
> Type, DataElementType, Expanded, FieldKey, ImgSource and Description